# Proving that $f(x)−x^p = g(x)$ has an infinite number of solutions for any continuous $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Taken from an exam paper of analysis:

Let $g : (0, 1] \to [−1, 1]$ be the function defined by $g(x) := \sin (\frac {\pi}{2x})$.

(i) Prove that for every continuous function $f : (0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ and for every $p\in\mathbb N$, the equation $f (x)−x^p = g(x)$ has an infinite number of solutions.
[Hint: Apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to the function $h(x) :=
f (x) − x^p − g(x)$ on suitable intervals.]

Got no idea how to proceed, even with the IVT.  Should I seek a proof by contradiction?

Comment: I think exam problem should not be posted

Comment: If you are able to prove a contradiction by assuming the existence of a continuous function $f:(0,1]\to[0,1]$ and some natural number $p$ such that $f(x)-\sin\frac\pi{2x}-x^p$ has finitely many zeros on $(0,1]$, then yes, you should.

Comment: @dust05 If the question is from an exam that has already passed and the results are official. Then it can be discussed. However, I think the most important thing here is that the OP shows its (true) attempts to solve the problem and where it is stuck.

Comment: It's past exam question indeed. I got suggested to consider intervals $I_n = [ \frac{1}{4n+1} , \frac{1}{4n-1} ] $ so that there would be some value of x such that $h(x) = 0 $, yet I don't know how to show that there are infinite number of those.

Comment: @dust05 It's [not our responsibility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252810/259305) to police online tests/exams.  For closing as ongoing contests questions, publicly accessible URL and contest end date should be notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint you have referenced goes a long way:  first observe that as $n$ varies the intervals $\left[\frac{1}{4n+1}, \frac{1}{4n-1}\right]$ are mutually disjoint.  This is easy to verify as the right hand end of one interval $n$ is less than left hand end of the interval $n-1$, and similarly the left hand end of interval $n$ is greater than the right hand end of interval $n+1$, as follows from
$$ 4n-1 > 4(n-1)+1, \text{ when }n > 1 \quad{and}\quad
4n+1 < 4(n+1)-1, \text{ when } n\geqslant 1.$$

Also,
$$ g\left(\frac{1}{4n+1}\right) = \sin\left(2n\pi+\frac{1}{2}\pi\right) = 1$$ and
$$g\left(\frac{1}{4n-1}\right) = \sin\left(2n\pi - \frac{1}{2}\pi\right)=-1.$$
Then, when $n \geqslant 1$, and using the given fact $0 \leqslant f(x) \leqslant 1$,
$$f\left(\frac{1}{4n+1}\right) - \frac{1}{(4n+1)^p}-g\left(\frac{1}{4n+1}\right) \leqslant 1-\frac{1}{(4n+1)^p}-1<0,$$
while
$$f\left(\frac{1}{4n-1}\right) - \frac{1}{(4n-1)^p}-g\left(\frac{1}{4n-1}\right) \geqslant 0-\frac{1}{(4n+1)^p}+1>0.$$
By the intermediate value theorem $f(x) - x^p -g(x)$ will have a zero inside the interval.  Each interval is disjoint from the others, so you obtain the result you needed.